# Remove Vimeo video controls from Iframe

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, vimeo

I'm using Vimeo video to set slider revolution background, I want to remove controls ( Share buttons, "Click tu unmute" ).

I've tried `.vp-unmute{ display:none !Important; }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You cant manipulate iframe content like that. Check the Vimeo player documentation instead https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed

Comment: Are you using embed code or does the plugin your using have a place where you just add the video link?